# Acf Post Object

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Please help me, I am using advanced custom fields and I created a field of type object post where I selected the posttype "product", I want to display the image of the product inside the loop but I am not able to

I will leave below the code of the display loop

```
<?php
$featured_posts = get_field('featured_posts');
if( $featured_posts ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $featured_posts as $featured_post ): 
        $permalink = get_permalink( $featured_post->ID );
        $title = get_the_title( $featured_post->ID );
        $custom_field = get_field( 'field_name', $featured_post->ID );
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $permalink ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></a>
            <span>A custom field from this post: <?php echo esc_html( $custom_field ); ?></span>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Where is your code to show an image?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you setup your ACF POST object RETURN parameter.
It can be set to ID or POST object. But it can't be set to post_title. In your given code you try to use title by that way.

Anyway, you can call it via native WP function. Like this:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach( $featured_posts as $featured_post ): 
    $permalink = get_permalink( $featured_post->ID );
    $title = get_the_title( $featured_post->ID );
    $custom_field_ID = get_post_meta( $featured_post->ID,'field_name',true);
    if ($custom_field_ID){$custom_field_post_object=get_post($custom_field_ID);}
    $custom_field_title='';
    if(!empty($custom_field_post_object)){
       $custom_field_title=$custom_field_post_object->post_title;
    }
    ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $permalink ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></a>
        <span>A custom field from this post: <?php echo esc_html( $custom_field_title ); ?></span>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is set to wp_post, how do I display the post image inside this code?

Comment: You mean featured image of the post? You can use  wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($featured_post->ID), 'full' )[0]; to get image source URL.